# Joint estimation of item and ability parameters

Tags: latent-variable, item-response-theory

Most Common Approach of estimation is Marginal Maximum Likelihood.
Other procedures: 
1) Joint Maximum Likelihood (Rasch only);
2) Markov Chain Monte Carlo(MCMC): Typically only used for highly parameterized models.

Which python or R packages do this estimation?

Comment: I don't know of any python package; but for R (besides the task view) there is also the helpfull search-engine: http://rseek.org/

Comment: There are lots of packages for R, but I think ltm is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of IRT packages over at CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html